# Upgrading from Ionic 3 to 5 - .map no longer works on observables

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, rxjs

How would I go about changing this code in Ionic 3 to Ionic 5 upgrade when the error states: Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable'.

```
return XApi.addTransaction('clicksActive', parameters, 
   { timeout: AppConfig.OTP_REQUEST_TIMEOUT, queue: false })
.map(res => {
        let response = res.data;
        let clicksActive: ClicksActive = this.parseActiveResponse(response);
        return clicksActive;
    }).catch(error => {
        let errorMessage = getLambdaErrorMessage(error);
        let clicksActive: ClicksActive = {
            success: false,
            active: false,
            errorMessage: errorMessage
        }
        return Observable.of(clicksActive);
    });
```

I tried changing it to:

```
return XApi.addTransaction('clicksActive', parameters, 
{ timeout: AppConfig.OTP_REQUEST_TIMEOUT, queue: false })
.pipe(map(res => {
        let response = res.data;
        let clicksActive: ClicksActive = this.parseActiveResponse(response);
        return clicksActive;
    })).catch(error => {
        let errorMessage = getLambdaErrorMessage(error);
        let clicksActive: ClicksActive = {
            success: false,
            active: false,
            errorMessage: errorMessage
        }

        return Observable.of(clicksActive);
    });
```

But then I get error:
Argument of type 'OperatorFunction<any, ClicksActive>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'UnaryFunction<Observable, Observable>'.
Types of parameters 'source' and 'source' are incompatible.
Type 'Observable' is missing the following properties from type 'Observable': buffer, bufferCount, bufferTime, bufferToggle, and 104

UPDATED:
Here is my updated code for the entire service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx'
import { AppConfig } from '../config/app-config';
import { XApi  } from 'x-lib';

import { ClicksActive, ClicksBalance } from '../models/user.model';
import { getLambdaErrorMessage } from "../helpers/lambda-error.helper";
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';


@Injectable()
export class ClicksService {

    constructor() {
    }

    requestActive(
        idNumber: String
    ): Observable<ClicksActive> {

        let parameters =
        {
            apiUsername: this.getApiUsername(),
            apiPassword: this.getApiPassword(),
            apiBaseUrl: this.getApiBaseUrl(),
            idNumber: idNumber
        }

        return XApi.addTransaction('clicksActive', parameters, { timeout: AppConfig.OTP_REQUEST_TIMEOUT, queue: false })
        .pipe(
            map((res) => {
            let response = res.data;
            let clicksActive: ClicksActive = this.parseActiveResponse(response);
            return clicksActive;
        }), catchError((error) => {
            let errorMessage = getLambdaErrorMessage(error);
            let clicksActive: ClicksActive = {
                success: false,
                active: false,
                errorMessage: errorMessage
            }

            return Observable.of(clicksActive);
        })
        );
    }
   




      
    parseActiveResponse(response): ClicksActive {
        let clicksActive: ClicksActive = {
            success: response.success,
            active: response.active,
            errorMessage: response.errorMessage
        }
        return clicksActive;
    }

    requestBalance(
        idNumber: String
    ): Observable<ClicksBalance> {

        let parameters =
        {
            apiUsername: this.getApiUsername(),
            apiPassword: this.getApiPassword(),
            apiBaseUrl: this.getApiBaseUrl(),
            idNumber: idNumber
        }

        /*let clicksBalance: ClicksBalance = {
            success: true,
            balance :{
              cardNumber: '123456789',
              amount: 110,
              limit: 220,
              timestamp: Date()
            },
            errorMessage: ""
        };

        return Observable.of(clicksBalance);*/
        return XApi.addTransaction('clicksBalance', parameters, { timeout: AppConfig.OTP_REQUEST_TIMEOUT, queue: false }).map(res => {
            let response = res.data;
            let clicksBalance: ClicksBalance = this.parseBalanceResponse(response);
            return clicksBalance;
        }).catch(error => {
            let errorMessage = getLambdaErrorMessage(error);
            let clicksBalance: ClicksBalance = {
                success: false,
                balance :{
                  cardNumber: '',
                  amount: 0,
                  limit: 0,
                  timestamp: null
                },
                errorMessage: errorMessage
            };

            return Observable.of(clicksBalance);
        });
    }

    /* GENERIC SERVICES */
    getApiUsername(): String {
        if (AppConfig.ENVIRONMENT == 'dev') {
            return AppConfig.DEV_API_USERNAME;
        }
        else if (AppConfig.ENVIRONMENT == 'qas') {
            return AppConfig.QAS_API_USERNAME;
        }
        else if (AppConfig.ENVIRONMENT == 'prd') {
            return AppConfig.PRD_API_USERNAME;
        }
    }

    getApiPassword(): String {
        if (AppConfig.ENVIRONMENT == 'dev') {
            return AppConfig.DEV_API_PASSWORD;
        }
        else if (AppConfig.ENVIRONMENT == 'qas') {
            return AppConfig.QAS_API_PASSWORD;
        }
        else if (AppConfig.ENVIRONMENT == 'prd') {
            return AppConfig.PRD_API_PASSWORD;
        }
    }

    getApiBaseUrl(): String {
        if (AppConfig.ENVIRONMENT == 'dev') {
            return AppConfig.DEV_API_BASE_URL;
        }
        else if (AppConfig.ENVIRONMENT == 'qas') {
            return AppConfig.QAS_API_BASE_URL;
        }
        else if (AppConfig.ENVIRONMENT == 'prd') {
            return AppConfig.PRD_API_BASE_URL;
        }
    }

    parseBalanceResponse(response): ClicksBalance {
        if(response.success){
            let clicksBalance: ClicksBalance = {
                success: response.success,
                balance :{
                  cardNumber: response.balance.cardNumber,
                  amount: response.balance.amount,
                  limit: response.balance.limit,
                  timestamp: response.balance.timestamp
                },
                errorMessage: response.errorMessage
            }
            return clicksBalance;
        }
        else{
            let clicksBalance: ClicksBalance = {
                success: response.success,
                balance : response.balance,
                errorMessage: response.errorMessage
            }
            return clicksBalance;
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you add more details of where the error is happen? Which line or what method throws this error?

Comment: Hi there, I've updated my question to include more the entire clicks.service.ts code.  You will see I used pipe() in the first instance, but it's not working - error is Argument of type 'OperatorFunction<any, ClicksActive>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'UnaryFunction<Observable<any>, Observable<ClicksActive>>'.
  Types of parameters 'source' and 'source' are incompatible.
    Type 'Observable<any>' is missing the following properties from type 'Observable<any>': buffer, bufferCount, bufferTime, bufferToggle, and 104 more.

Comment: Any ideas @E.Maggini based on my updated code?

Answer (score 0):

You're using the new Rxjs along with Ionic 5 so you need to use the pipe function and the new operators. Here a guide to this migration: https://ionicframework.com/docs/reference/migration

However, in order to fix your problem you need to call map and catchError operators this way:

```js
  call(): Observable<{}>{
    return this.addTransaction() // <- simulate the observable which add a transaction
      .pipe(
        map((res) => {
          // your logic here on success
          // ...

          return {};  // I am using {} but you need to apply your payload
        }),
        catchError((error) => {
          // your logic here on error
          // ...

          return of({}); // I am using {} but you need to apply your payload
        })
      );
  }

  addTransaction(): Observable<{}>{
    return of({}); // I am using {} but you need to apply your payload
  }
```

Comment: Thank you - I've updated my question to include more code - you will see in first instance I've tried to use your pipe() suggestion, but I'm still getting the same error as per my question.

Comment: Any ideas @bjdose based on my updated code?

Comment: You need to import Observable from rxjs only, so try using `import { Observable } from 'rxjs'` instead of `import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';`

Comment: Hi @bjdose it doesn't make any difference how I import Observable. Any other ideas?